# Making and using a foreign key for relation in SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin

Suposse that i have an android studio App where i can add companies, and inside those companies i can also add employees. Now, i'm trying to get the employees list showing only the elements of the company I selected before (In an unique activity for showing employees).

I created two classes:

```
data class Company(val id:Int, val name:String, val telephone:String)
data class Employee (val id:Int, val name:String, val telephone:String, val idCompany:Int)
```

And in my SQLiteHelper I created the tables for each one, with a foreign key in Employees to make a relation

```
    private val TABLE_COMPANY = "CompanyTable"
    private val TABLE_EMPLOYEE = "EmployeeTable"


    //Company table
    private val COMPANY_ID = "_id"
    private val COMPANY_NAME = "name"
    private val COMPANY_TL = "telephone"

    //Employee table
    private val EMPLOYEE_ID = "id"
    private val EMPLOYEE_NAME = "name"
    private val EMPLOYEE_TL = "telephone"
    private val EMPLOYEE_COMPANY_ID = "id"



}

override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase?) {

    val CREATE_COMPANY_TABLE = ("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_COMPANY + "("
            + COMPANY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + COMPANY_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + COMPANY_TL + " TEXT" + ")")

    val CREATE_EMPLOYEE_TABLE = ("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_EMPLOYEE + "("
            + EMPLOYEE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + EMPLOYEE_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + EMPLOYEE_TL + " INTEGER,"
            + EMPLOYEE_COMPANY_ID + " INTEGER,"
            + " FOREIGN KEY ("+ EMPLOYEE_COMPANY_ID+") REFERENCES "+TABLE_COMPANY+"("+ COMPANY_ID+"))")


    db?.execSQL(CREATE_EMPLOYEE_TABLE)
    db?.execSQL(CREATE_COMPANY_TABLE)

}
```

So, I made two activities with recyclerviews, one for the Companies and the other for the employees.
When i click a company, the employees activity opens and it shows a list of them.

But it shows all the employees i have, so i'm trying to figure out how to show only the ones that i saved with the same id of the Company that i clicked in the previous activity.

But i don't know how to proceed now

Here is the DAO function that shows the employees:

```
fun viewEmployee(): ArrayList<Employee> {

    val empList: ArrayList<Employee> = ArrayList<Employee>()

    // Query to select the records
    val selectQuery = "SELECT L.$EMPLOYEE_NAME, L.$EMPLOYEE_TL, L.$EMPLOYEE_ID, L.$EMPLOYEE_COMPANY_ID, C.$COMPANY_ID" +
            "FROM $TABLE_EMPLOYEE as L, $TABLE_COMPANY as C" +
            "WHERE L.$EMPLOYEE_COMPANY_ID = C.$COMPANY_ID"



    val db = this.readableDatabase
   
    var cursor: Cursor? = null

    try {
        cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null)

    } catch (e: SQLiteException) {
        db.execSQL(selectQuery)
        return ArrayList()
    }

    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var telephone: String
    var idCompany: Int

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(EMPLOYEE_ID))
            name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EMPLOYEE_NAME))
            telephone = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(EMPLOYEE_TL))
            idCompany = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(EMPLOYEE_COMPANY_ID))

            val employee = Employee(id = id, name = name, telephone = telephone, idCompany = idCompany)
            empList.add(employee)

        } while (cursor.moveToNext())
    }
    return empList
}
```

And here is the activity that shows the employees

```
class ManagerEmp : AppCompatActivity() {




override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_manager_emp)

    setList()
    
    createEmp.setOnClickListener{
        val intent = Intent(this, CreateEmp::class.java)
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}





/**
 * Gets DB employee list
 */
private fun getItemsList(): ArrayList<Employee> {
    //creating the instance of DatabaseHandler class
    val databaseHandler = DataBaseHelper(this)
    //calling the viewEmployee method of DatabaseHandler class to read the records
    val empList: ArrayList<Employee> = databaseHandler.viewEmployee()

    return empList
}



/**
 * Generates the list
 */
private fun setList() {

    recyclerEmp.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    val itemAdapter = empAdapter(this, getItemsList())
    recyclerEmp.adapter = itemAdapter
}
```

}

It sounds simple but it isn't (At least for me)
I thought of getting the id value of the company and pass it to the employee list activity, so i can use to compare it, but idk how, i'm pretty new in kotlin (And programming in general)

If you can give an answer, you would be saving my life.

H E L P

Comment: Hi, it's better if you use Room Api from Android ( you don't have to manage Cursor etc ...) and see https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships , for your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to obtain `companyId` you want to filter by. It can be done for example by [adding onClickListener in RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick).

Then you will need additional query which will be used for filtering by companyId.

For example if `companyId` is stored in `filteredCompanyId` variable you can add additional filter condition (`WHERE ... AND C.$COMPANY_ID == $filteredCompanyId`):

```
val filteredCompanyId = 5
val query = """
SELECT L.$EMPLOYEE_NAME, 
       L.$EMPLOYEE_TL, 
       L.$EMPLOYEE_ID, 
       L.$EMPLOYEE_COMPANY_ID, 
       C.$COMPANY_ID 
FROM   $TABLE_EMPLOYEE AS L, 
       $TABLE_COMPANY AS C 
WHERE  L.$EMPLOYEE_COMPANY_ID = C.$COMPANY_ID 
       AND C.$COMPANY_ID == $filteredCompanyId
"""
```

Comment: So, i have to define an Int variable in my DAO and use it in the query?

Comment: Ok, i just did it, i added a filtering parameter inside the DAO function, then, in the company activity, i used an intent to pass the id of the clicked company to the employee activity. Then I call that id as companyId and call the DAO function putting companyId val inside the parameter. THANKS A LOT